# How can I replace date modified with date last saved?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to organize a large number of .doc and .docx files, but it appears that their "Date modified" and "Date created" metadata are incorrect — probably it was all lost during a move a while back. The "Date last saved" and "Content created" metadata appear to be correct, however, so I'm wondering: is it possible to use Powershell to replace the "Date modified" and "Date created" fields with the information from the "Date last saved" and "Content created" fields?

Comment: Sure it's possible. Simply read the metadata from the file and modify the file's attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreationTime` and `LastWriteTime` are filesystem properties, you can get and set them using `get-itemproperty` and `set-itemproperty`.

`Creation date` and `Last save time` are word-specific properties.
[The Scripting Guy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/12/29/hey-scripting-guy-december-29-2009.aspx) tells you how to read them.
Once you read them, set them with `set-itemproperty`.

Here's an example on how to read the two word properties and write them to the filesystem properties for all `*.doc` and `*.docx` files in the current directory.

```
$includeExtensions = @(".doc", ".docx") 
$path = "."
$docs = Get-ChildItem -Path $path | ?{$includeExtensions -contains $_.Extension}

foreach($doc in $docs) {
    $application = New-Object -ComObject word.application
    $application.Visible = $false
    $document = $application.documents.open($doc.FullName)
    $binding = "System.Reflection.BindingFlags" -as [type]
    $properties = $document.BuiltInDocumentProperties

    $lastsavetime = $null
    $creationdate = $null

    foreach($property in $properties)
    {
     $pn = [System.__ComObject].invokemember("name",$binding::GetProperty,$null,$property,$null)
      trap [system.exception]
       {
        continue
       }
       if($pn -eq "Last save time") {
            $lastsavetime = [System.__ComObject].invokemember("value",$binding::GetProperty,$null,$property,$null)
       } elseif ($pn -eq "Creation date") {
            $creationdate = [System.__ComObject].invokemember("value",$binding::GetProperty,$null,$property,$null)
       }                
    }

    $document.Close()
    $application.quit()

    "Setting " + $doc.FullName
    Set-ItemProperty $doc.FullName -Name "Creationtime" -Value $creationdate 
    Set-ItemProperty $doc.FullName -Name "LastWriteTime" -Value $lastsavetime 

}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! I'm sorry, but I really don't know what I'm doing. I've figured out how to get a list of all the `.doc` and `.docx` files that I need to change with

`$includeExtensions  = @(".doc", ".docx")
Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\Google Drive\Actual Documents\Poems" | ?{$includeExtensions -contains $_.Extension}`

But I don't know how to pass this on to the second part of the script, specifically `$application.documents.open`.

I also don't know how to save the values of `Creation date` and `Last save time` as variables from within that section of the script.

Comment: So what you are basically saying is you don't have the slightest idea of basic PowerShell or programming concepts. See the edited answer for a full working code. Please mark it as correct answer.