# Replacing word-specific timestamps with system time stamps or arbitrary time stamps

Tags: powershell, ms-word, metadata

I've read through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148479/how-can-i-replace-date-modified-with-date-last-saved) but my aim is to go the opposite route. I have a word document that I can successfully change CreationTime, LastAccessTime, and LastWriteTime with a fairly straightforward powershell command. Example:

```
gci | ?{$_.Name -eq "MyWordFile.docx"} | foreach-object{$_.CreationTime = $_.CreationTime.AddDays(-30)
```

This will put the creation date for the file to 30 days prior to what it currently is. The problem I have is that I'm using fields in the Word file referencing CreateDate, SaveDate and the likes. These seem to reference back to the Word-specific meta data that is 'Content created' and 'Date last saved'.

The post that I referenced above shows how to take the Content created and replace the CreationTime system value with it, but I'm looking at modifying the actual Content created field. I tried modifying the original line:

```
$creationdate = [System.__ComObject].invokemember("value",$binding::GetProperty,$null,$property,$null)
```

With using ::SetProperty instead, but the problem is that I don't know how the .invokemember is referencing the values from the file, so I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you run your code, open the document in Word, click on the field and press F9 to force it to update does it display the information you want/expect?

Comment: Nope, the fields in Word being used are 'CreatedDate' and 'SaveDate' and these reference back to the extended meta data that Word uses. My modification doesn't actually change the property of the file, which presumably is because either the change from GetProperty to SetProperty is not complete (need other parameters) or that I'm not saving the file after the change, or I'm calling it incorrectly etc. If there's an easier way that doesn't require PowerShell to modify the extended meta data I'm happy to check that :)